# Is it worth pooling byte[] and char[] arrays or is it better to just create

Tags: java, performance

My code does a lot of Input/Output and this often involves the creation of temporary arrays to hold bytes or chars of some size - i often use 4096. Im starting to wonder - without actual tests - to verify if it would be better to pool these arrays. My code would change to something like this

```
take array from pool
try {
   read from one inputStream
   write to another outputstream using array
} finally {
   return array to pool
}
```

- it is quicker to take or simply create a byte with 4096 which means some work is required to alloc mem on the heap, clear the 4096 bytes etc.
- a pool seems simpler after all its probably just checking a list taking from the list and returning the array.

UPDATE
I wrote a small program that did two things, created arrays and used an apache commons pool. Both looped a lot of times (100*100*100) and created/took, filled array, then released. I added a few goes in the beginning to warm up the jit and ignored the results of those. Each run ran the create and pool forms a dozen times, alternating between the two.

There was little difference between the pool and create forms. However if i added a clear array to the callback that is fired by apache commons pool when an instance is returned to a pool, the pool became that much slower thanthe created form.

Comment: Do you do these operations in parallel or could you just reuse an existing array over and over again?

Comment: Micro-optimization detected. The JVM is very efficient at small object allocation and de-allocation -- especially if they are short-lived. Dealing with a pool adds another layer of complexity and I would *not* go down that route (again) unless there was an *analyzed* performance issue. There are even extreme edge cases where pooling may *severely decrease performance* over a new allocation based on data-locality!

Comment: @Timo in parallel - imagine a typical web app.

Comment: @pst yes the JVM is efficient lets imagine that allocating space for the array is almost free, but it still needs to clear the array before handing you back an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer but some important points to consider if one wants to use array pooling as opposed to creation each time an array is required.

- creating an array is portional to the number of elements.
- acquiring and releasing an array back to the pool has some fixed cost.
- if the array is greater than 4096 elements the overhead of the pool is less than the cost of creation.
- creating an array is cheaper than clearing the array if it important that the contents be cleared.
- sharing an array should not be done if sensitive data may appear in the array because there is no way to guarantee that code returning the array may still hold onto a reference.

Answer (score 6):

I would not implement pooling until a performance problem was demonstrated.

Comment: Your concern can be answered by the fact that one pool implementationcould be made to create an array each time took is called. It also means that one can tune the buffersize in global manner w/out hardcoding or passing an exact size around.

Comment: @mP - but why waste your time doing it?  This "dummy pool" approach is only useful for measuring whether pooling was worth implementing *after the fact* ... and for changing your mind without actually undoing the code changes you made to implement and use the Pooling API.

Answer (score 4):

Object pools add complexity to an application.  In general, you have to deal with:

- implementing the acquire / release operations in a thread-safe fashion,
- ensuring that objects are always released, and are never retained / used after release,
- making sure that released objects are "cleaned" before the next acquire, and
- growing and shrinking the pool size.

If you make a mistake in the pool implementation, you can introduce insidious bugs.

Is it worth it?  Well, the answer depends on the circumstances:

- If memory is severely constrained, GC pauses are a major issue, and/or the cost of allocating and initializing an object is large, then probably yes.
- If the cost of "cleaning" and object is roughly the same as the amortized cost of allocating a new one, then it is doubtful.

To understand the last point, you need to understand some basic copying GC ergonomics.  Specifically if you:

- assume a constant sized working set of reachable objects,
- ignore object finalization and soft/weak/phantom references, and
- increase the total heap size towards infinity,

then the amortized GC cost of allocating and reclaiming memory for object in Java *approaches* the cost of zeroing memory.

Thus, if the cost of cleaning an object is roughly equivalent to the GC overhead (zeroing) + the object constructor cost, then the only thing you gain by pooling is reducing the number of times the GC marking / copying occurs.  But you can do the same thing by simply giving the application a larger heap.

Comment: Firstly the pool(its an interface) does not have to be a pool, another strategy is to implement a factory. It is impossible to ensure that someone does not hang onto an array even if they give it back - because one cannot wrap the array w/ a guard that prevents usage by them after returning.

Comment: @mP - the OP asked about pools. EXPLICITLY.  Also, a factory does not achieve the goal of recycling the arrays / buffers / whatever, unless the factory is a wrapper for some kind of pool.

Comment: Firstly the pool interface does allow a factory to be squeezed in behind the scenes. On the other hand the same is not true in reverse, a factory interface w/ just create() does not have a release() method to give something back making it impossible to be a pool.

Comment: Just because it says "Pool" does not mean it has to be a pool, a factory that hands out new arrays would not break any clients, even if it were perceived to be inefficient compared to a true pooling implmenetation.

Comment: @mP - I don't know what you are on about.  The whole point of the OP's question is about recycling objects.  The classic Factory pattern doesn't allow this, so it is (IMO) irrelevant to the question.  When you add the extra method(s) to allow recycling, you are using the Pool pattern.

Comment: @StephenC, the Pool interface could for arguments sake be a factory that creates a new array each time Pool.take() is called and simply ignore the array passed to Pool.release(array).

Comment: @mP - ... thereby not recycling the object, and rendering the exercise of implementing pooling pointless.  (OK ... not entirely pointless.  You can use this approach *after the fact* to measure whether you have wasted your time by implementing pooling.)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using the `java.nio.Buffer` classes. For example, you could have something like this:

```
class ReadWorker {
    private ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);

    public void work() {
        fillBufferWithData();
        buffer.flip();
        doSomethingWithData();
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
```

Each call to `work` will clear the buffer ready for the next call but you won't be allocating/deallocating memory all the time. `flip` and `clear` are very fast operations.

Having one `Buffer` per worker will be easier than creating a pool with it's associated synchronisation fun-and-games.

EDIT: Note that I'm assuming you generate a fixed pool of workers so you're not creating new `Buffer` objects all the time.

If you can't have a fixed worker pool then you could consider creating a pool of `Buffer` objects rather than raw byte arrays. It depends on how you are using them.

Comment: Wont work because most apis use the old io InputStream/OUtputStream/Reader/Writer classes.

Comment: There are really two parts to this suggestion. (1) use a ByteBuffer; (2) make it a member of the using class. (1) is only viable if he is using NIO. (2) is only viable if the class isn't used by multiple threads.

Comment: @EJP: (2) is only viable if each *instance* of the class isn't used by multiple threads. Each worker thread can have an instance quite happily.

Comment: @EJP what Cameron said- tankx Cameron.

Comment: Correct, thanks, sloppy work on my part. I should also have added (3) each buffer is only used by one method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  If you have to do a lot of these input/output tasks, pooling will improve performance and keep the memory footprint smaller.

Comment: It sounds nice, but, proof/example where?

Comment: Memory: Take the above mentioned arrays of size 4096.  Each time you create a new one, you allocate 4096 bytes of memory.  When you're done, you send it to the garbage collector, which later on destroys it.  Until garbage collection is executed, the memory will remain reserved, so the footprint of the program is larger than necessary. You have no control over that.  When you use pooling, you create a reasonable amount of arrays at program start, in order to deal with a little more than the average load. You have a large initial footprint, but the program is not likely to grow beyond reason.

Comment: Performance: Every time you create an array, memory has to be allocated, and an entry to the lookup table must be made. Every time garbage is collected, unused memory must be freed up.  In a pool, all you do is look up an address.  I agree, this is minimal. Unless you have a great number of tasks, maybe even with a high variation between lows and highs.  Then it will become a factor.

Comment: My little micro test sort of prooves that using a pool does not really hurt performance. The true benefit is the ability to use the pool as a buffer provider where my buffer size is not hardcoded or a parameter to some class but rather its extracted into some other component. In this case introducing an abstraction helps and gives me options. The main q is it worth the bother. The one bad thing is that takers can hang onto the buffer.